# function onEdit doesn't fire in Google sheet add-on

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building a simple Google Sheet add-on, and in my code I have the function `onEdit()` that ([according to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit)) should fire when the user changes some cell, but it does not!

Here is my code:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Scheduller')
    .addItem('Some item', 'Some item')
    .addToUi()
}

// This function is not called when the user change the value of some cell
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range

  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date())
}
```

Some suggestion?

Comment: You can create the trigger yourself on the edit menu in Code Editor and assign to anyfunction you like. Add a parameter to it and the event data will be loaded into it.

Comment: You might want to check out the restrictions on simple triggers [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit).  That may be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the `onEdit` event to fire you need to set up a trigger.

You can do it by programmatically:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEdit')
      .onEdit()
      .create();
```

or you can do it [manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).